# 3-way solenoid valve gets hot

Tags: solenoid-valve, overheat

I have this Bosch 3-way valve that I use in a hydronic system.

If I run 12V to energize the valve, it gets very HOT!

Is that normal with such valves?

[image: 1]]

[image: 2]]

Comment: puh, do you have a datasheet for that? Might be totally OK, or you might be using an overly high voltage...

Comment: No, I can't find it on Bosch https://www.bosch-automotive-catalog.com/en/product-detail/-/product/1147412163 I use it in my van, just 12V.

Comment: 12 V is a voltage, not a current.

Comment: corrected, thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is definitely an on/off valve, which is designed to be either fully operated or fully released - see note below - then you can **reduce the power it dissipates by reducing the drive power after you initially operate it.** Solenoid-operated devices like valves and relays can normally maintain their 'on' state with a considerably lower coil current (*holding current*) than is necessary to switch them from 'off' to 'on' (*operating current*) though. After an initial 'hit' of the rated supply voltage to operate the valve, you should find you can reduce the voltage/current to a lower level and it will stay open quite happily with a lot less power.

You could devise a clever circuit to do this but unless you're short of space the easiest way is to use one resistor and one capacitor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDGcSS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

L1 is the valve coil. Start by measuring its DC resistance, by connecting a multimeter on resistance range to the two coil terminals. You'll need to experiment with the values of R1 and C1 but I would start with R1 about the same as the resistance of the coil and C1 chosen for a time constant of about a second with that resistance, i.e. if L1 measures 100 ohms then try 10 000 µF for C1, if 50 ohms try about 20 000 µF, and so on. D1 is there to protect C1 from a voltage spike when you switch the power off; a 1N4000 type rectifier diode should be fine.

Obviously C1 must be rated for at least your drive voltage, and R1 must be rated for the power that it will dissipate. For example if the coil has a DC resistance of 60 ohms and R1 is also 60 ohms then once C1 has charged the current through R1 and the coil will be 0.1 A, and R1 and the coil will dissipate 0.6 W each.

One catch with this circuit is that if you try to switch the valve off then on again less than a few seconds afterwards, C1 will not have time to fully discharge through R1 and so the valve may not operate properly. Another is that if the coil resistance is really low, the size and cost of C1 may become impractical. If either of those is a possibility you may have to use something more complex e.g. a monostable timer to generate the 'hit' pulse - if so, ask and someone can help you further.

**Note:** if you had a proportioning valve i.e. one that partially opens one port and closes the other *in proportion to* the drive current, then this technique would not work well. In that case you could experiment with putting a resistor in series to reduce the current, as perhaps you wouldn't need the full 12 volts to fully close the 'normally open' port.

Comment: Yes exactly, opens one port and closes another. Here is a similar vale: https://www.butlertechnik.com/images/eberspacher-water-valve-12v-3-port-20mm-kit-292180010030-p2722-4210_image.jpg looking at the electrical requirements i think you hit the nail on the head..

Comment: I also have to tell you that I have been opening and closing the valve quickly in a short time, for testing, could that be the reason for it getting hot? Maybe I should test leaving it open for 10 minutes or so and see if it get's hot.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in the first paragraph - I'm asking if this is a normal valve where each port is either fully open or fully closed, or whether it is capable of dividing the flow between the two outlets in a variable proportion according to the drive current - that's not so common, but I'm not familiar with automotive HVAC systems which appears to be the application of the one you have.

Comment: To answer your second comment, no, it's not the act of switching on and off that causes the heat, it's the continuous flow of current through the resistance of the coil while the valve is energised. If continuously on it will get hottest. What is the resistance of your valve's coil? The one you link to in the comments will dissipate 13 or 14 W while energised, which is quite a lot. Possibly it's designed to always have some liquid flow through it which helps to cool it?

Comment: Thanks for the help and time to explain this to me. I am a noob with these things though.. yes the valve opens or closes, not half way gradually if that is what you mean. I have an hydronic heater that I use standalone without the engine on to warm up the coolant liquid. With this valve I want to choose between full circuit including the engine block (no voltage going to the valve) or bypass the engine block (12V applied) I have no idea of the resistance of the coil, is there a way to measure this or should I find that in the data sheet, which I don't have.

Comment: I tested this morning running the heater with voltage applied to the solenoid for about 15 minutes and it gets hot, not burning hot, but still hot.

Comment: See edit. If you can update with the resistance you measure, we can decide whether this answer is the best way of doing it or not.